# Find a value within a list in that list's definition Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, indexing

Say I have the list

```
main = ["Hello", "World"]
```

Is it possible, at all, within definition, to refer to first item of list. By that I mean something like this

```
main = ["Hello", main[0] + " World!"]
```

so that `main[1]` would return `Hello World!`? The current syntax does not work and was wondering why this is and is there a working alternative/fix?

I apologize if this is a stupid question, im still kinda new to python but thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can't because when the `[...]` list definition is run, the object doesn't yet exist, nor is it assigned to any name yet.

You'll have to use a second line; you can always alter elements once the list is created and bound:

```
main = ["Hello", "World"]
main[1] = main[0] + main[1]
```

or append new elements:

```
main = ["Hello"]
main.append(main[0] + "World")
```

Comment: You can also redefine `main` after the list has been defined initially. Running  `main = ["Hello", "World"]` followed by `main = ["Hello", main[0] + " World!"]` will produce your desired output.

Comment: @BarFooBar: but would be rather and needlessly repetitive.

Comment: Sure, but it answers their question about in what context `main = ["Hello", main[0] + " World!"]` would work.